# boost graph library: dfs visitors filtering nodes

Tags: c++, boost, graph, depth-first-search

I have encountered the following problem with the booost graph library while building an agent-based model.
I have a directed graph representing agents and potential trades, defined as follows:

```
struct agent{
  int idhh;
  double askprice;
  double maxbid;
  bool is_seller;
  bool is_buyer;
};

typedef adjacency_list< listS, // Store out-edges of each vertex in a std::list
                       listS, // Store vertex set in a std::list
                       directedS,
                       // vertex properties
                       agent,
                       // edge properties
                       no_property
                       >
                       taGraph;

typedef graph_traits<taGraph>::vertices_size_type v_size_type;
typedef graph_traits<taGraph>::edges_size_type e_size_type;
typedef graph_traits<taGraph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
typedef graph_traits<taGraph>::vertex_iterator vertex_iter;
typedef graph_traits<taGraph>::edge_descriptor edge_t;
typedef graph_traits<taGraph>::out_edge_iterator out_edge_iter;
typedef graph_traits<taGraph>::in_edge_iterator in_edge_iter;
```

The vertex attributes can be ignored for this part of the problem. Now, for a given node v, I want to find one of two things:

- if node v is not a sink but has in-edges and out-edges, I want to find *some* cycle involving node v.
- if node v is a source in the network (i.e. has no incoming edges), I want to find *some* path to another node that is a sink (i.e. has no outgoing edges), and record that path.

Note that in both cases it is absolutely sufficient to find one path, not all. (In fact, we did an exhaustive search, but that proved to be infeasible for our purposes.)
I figured that we use depth-first search (dfs) as opposed to breadth-first search since it might give longer paths, which is desirable in our case.
I also found out that the solution lies in providing a visitor to the dfs. For the first problem, it should check on each examine_edge() whether the edge points to out starting vertex v, and in the second case, whether the edge points to a node with an out-degree of zero. If the condition is fulfilled, it throws an exception, in order to not search the complete graph.

I have gone through the examples provided at the boost website for dfs and dfs visitors. I have spent the last nights understanding how it works.But how to implement this specific case still somehow completely escapes me.

So, the concrete question is, since I have not succeeded at building the visitor correctly: what does the visitor need to look like?

Comment: Not clear exactly what your problem is.  You have described your needs well, so what exactly is the problem you have?  Is it coding the visitor?  coding the search?  What?

Comment: BTW you should look into bundled properties - so much easier!  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html

Comment: sorry about not being precise about the problem. I have failed so far at coding the visitor proprely. After that, as afar as my understanding goes, the search should be simple since I would just need to pass the visitor to depth_first_search. As for bundled properties: thanks for the hint, that was on my to-do list (The code comes form an older project from a colleague), just changed it now.

Comment: Have you seen filtered_graph?